# MySQL - order by one month from today

Tags: mysql

How to order records by one month from today. I have tried the following but it does not work.

```
WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE() -1 month)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?  This will get you everything in your table where the month of the `date` field is equal to the current month - 1:

```
WHERE MONTH(date) = month(curdate() - interval 1 month)
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! Will accept answer in 10 mins due to SO rules

Comment: Wouldn't this also return the same month of previous years?

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what you're after from your question, so I'm taking a punt that you want to show records that have the date that is exactly one month from now

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

That will get all entries for October, if we are currently in November.

If you want it down to the day, so if today is November 20 you want to grab items from October 20, you'll need something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM agentjobsets
WHERE DATE(created_at) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```